# Networking between .NET and Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, networking

I am trying to create an tool for myself that contains two parts, a C# WPF application and an Android application.

The Android app displays a UI which allows the user to adjust the volume of each individual application that is open on the PC which the WPF app is running on. Essentially acting as a remote windows volume mixer.

The program running on the PC has to be written in C-Sharp (or another .net language) because it needs access to the Windows Core Audio Library to adjust each programs audio volume.

I need some advice on how to approach the networking part of the project. I am not sure how I can send/receive data between platforms because I have limited experience with socket programming.

Here is some example code of how I was thinking of doing it:

```
// CLIENT (ANDROID APP)
SendVolume(int proccessID, float volume)
{
    //Send server proccessID and new volume level
}

// SERVER (WPF APP)
RecieveVolume(int proccessID, float volume)
{
    for(session in manager.getSessions())
    {
        if(session.getID() == proccessID)
        {
            SimpleAudioVolume volume = session.setVolume(volume);
            UpdateClients();
        {
    }
}

UpdateClients()
{
    //Send all android clients a list of all running applications and their corresponding volumes.
}
```

Are there any libraries that I can use to achieve this, and if not what do I need to know to do it myself?

Thanks!

Comment: `Sockets` over **TCP** might be what's required here. Assuming you can get Android to do that.

Comment: use client and server communication

Comment: by using the web service methods (REST/SOAP) you can communicate with your android and wcf

Comment: Client-server is an option but not on this case though.. he wants socket programming over 2 different languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host asp.net web api in your wpf application and then call it directly using http from android mobile if both are on same WiFi network. See this for hosting web api in a wpf app http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have recently started a class in asp.net so this could be a good solution. I will do some more research to make sure it can work and then accept this answer. Thanks